# Is it possible to create a form with input fields filling out all available space?

Tags: forms, html, css, input

i'm trying to create following layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/BTuMH/1/

but without setting the width, like:

http://jsfiddle.net/yuGyg/

is this possible?

Comment: without jumping to the next line, just filling up the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BTuMH/3/

Get rid off those divs, you don't need those? I've fiddled a somewhat cleaner version. Float the label (yes, you can use a `label` element instead of a `div` with class `label`) and use css to give the `input` maximum width.

**Update:**

This only works for firefox. This doesn't work for webkit. I hoped that using `display: block;` on the `input` element, it would calculate it's width by taking maximum space available behind the floated `label`. This does not work. I guess you'll have to use javascript to set the width after rendering the page.

**Yet another update:**
I've made it work!

See http://jsfiddle.net/BTuMH/4/

With `overflow: hidden;` on a `div` wrapper, the input element can get 100% width, where 100% width is the width of the `div`. It didn't work before because the space behind the floated element was also occupied by the `div`, using `overflow:hidden;` fixes that.

Comment: without jumping to the next line, just filling up the rest of the line.

Comment: nice works in FF! but it does not work in chrome/safari (webkit) :(

Comment: Whoops, yes there is! `overflow: hidden;` to the rescue.